# Callibrating. Is it adjustment? Help with translation

Tags: meaning

I was very doubtful about posting this question here or in the Japanese language section. However, although a translation question, it seems to me that this deals more with the english meaning of the word "callibrate".

I am looking to translate the japanese word 調整(chosei) which according to a quick dictionary search means:

[Meaning of chosei](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%AA%BF%E6%95%B4)

> accommodation（論争・紛争などの）
>   adjustment
>   alignment（部品などの）
>   conditioning（身体の）
>   conditioning（温度などの）
>   coordination
>   fitting（物の）
>   fix
>   fixing
>   liaison（軍の部隊同士などの）
>   reconciliation《会計》
>   rectification
>   regulation
>   true-up
>   tune-up

I think the closest meaning for me would be "adjustment". 
As in "module adjustment screen" but I am wondering if I could just say "Callibration" instead of adjustment.

So what does callibrating means exactly?  (I know the word, I have read the dictionary meaning- I am going for a native speaker opinion of what this word does mean and does not mean- where it would be wrong to use it)

Comment: I don't know if this is really answerable without more context.  It's not clear to me what "module adjustment screen" means out of context, and I can't really tell you whether *calibration* or *adjustment* is a more appropriate translation of 調整 without some additional information to narrow down the meaning.

Comment: I agree more context is needed, but based on [調整](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%AA%BF%E6%95%B4-568677), at least in a technical context it refers to adjustment to an accepted standard (calibration) or adjustment to an expected state or condition. But as the examples on alc point out, there is a lot of variation, no doubt based on the context involved.

Comment: On the English side, *adjustment* refers to any kind of change in some parameter or condition, while *calibration* refers to adjustment to some standardized state.

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam Webster, "calibrate" has a broad lexical field in everyday speech. According to Wikipedia, citing a technical definition from an international body, "calibrate" has a very narrow meaning in scientific usage.

Unless you mean the process of comparing a measuring device against a standard measure, I'd avoid the word as excessively broad.